# Best practice for Cucumber framework: files under support or lib?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I'm working in a new project where the tests are created with the cucumber framework and I was wondering, if I need to create new ruby code to expand the functionality. Where is best to create those, under support or under lib?

I've been googling for a while but I cannot seem to find the difference between what should go in which folder.

Could you guys point me in the right direction or give me an example for trying to understand this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anything related to facilitate the interaction of your test code with cucumber, place it in support... anything that is meant to facilitate the way you support your test code independent of cucumber, place it in lib outside of support... that's how I approach it but there isn't a rule...